# Insert into table based on comparison of two other tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I currently have a table of 15 million old-records (**table1**), another table of 11-million new records (**table2**) and an empty table (**table3**).

Both **table1** and **table2** share data - I would like find the records in table1 table that aren't present in **table2**, and then `insert` these into **table3**.

So far I have the following (which is returning an unknown column on table3.uniqueCode error):

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE table1.uniqueCode != table2.uniqueCode
```

I should note that table1 and table2 do not have the same structure, but both have the field of uniqueCode, this is not a KEY but just a literal unique string code.

Any help would be very much appreciated, I've looked into using a `JOIN` statement but I also encountered errors with this approach.

Thanks!

**Update - Answered**

The answer was simple:

```
INSERT INTO table3
(SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE uniqueCode not in (Select uniqueCode from table2))
```

There are an abundance for varied answers below which tailor to slightly different situations. Please look at those too as they may solve a slightly varied question you may have like this. :)

Comment: Could you add table descriptions (`DESCRIBE table1`, `DESCRIBE table2`, `DESCRIBE table3`) ?

Comment: Do you need a query for Mysql or Sql-Server?

Comment: I'm running these queries through the mySQL command line client. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the tables have the same structure:

```
INSERT INTO table3
(SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE uniqueCode not in (Select uniqueCode from table2))
```

Comment: This worked first time for me and was the first answer, simple and effective. Thanks! Although I would add - 'struktur' should be spelled as 'structure'.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
INSERT INTO table3 (uniqueCode)
SELECT t2.uniqueCode FROM table2 WHERE t2.uniqueCode 
NOT IN  
(SELECT t3.uniqueCode FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.uniqueCode = t2.uniqueCode)
```

Edited

```
INSERT INTO table3 (uniqueCode)
SELECT t2.uniqueCode FROM table2 WHERE t2.uniqueCode 
NOT IN  
(SELECT t1.uniqueCode FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.uniqueCode = t2.uniqueCode)
```

Comment: then what about this where condition WHERE table2.uniqueCode != table3.uniqueCode?

Answer (score 0):

Use Merge statement in sql. See the example http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

```
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S
ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
    THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:
first we should to select records in `table1` that not exists in `table2`(according to your question)
if `uniqueCode` is a unique code (KEY) then:

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uniqueCode NOT IN (SELECT uniqueCode FROM table2)`

now we should to insert these result into `table3` ,so:

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uniqueCode NOT IN (SELECT uniqueCode FROM table2)
```

and done...

Attention: all 3 tables must have same structure in this answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare rows and you have not got a unique column (you want to compare all columns) you can use [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) clause like this:

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT *
FROM tabel1
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **UNION** will be the best option to use between two table.
Like :

`SELECT t1.*  FROM table1 t1 UNION SELECT t2.* FROM table2 t2`